# How to generate an associated connection

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

I know that we can generate an affine connection on a GL(n) bundle.If we have a fibre bundle whose structure group G is the subgroup of GL(n) with diagonalizable matrices M whose eigenvalues are +1 or -1 (and for which there must be at least one eigenvalue of -1) and the Identity I( ie G={M,I:M^2=I} but M is unequal to I), how can I generate a connection 1-form on the G-bundle which is related to the affine connection on GL(n)?

Pls I would also like it localized to show each index.I hope I got the message across. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can anyone please help me out here

Comment: It looks like the Lie algebra of $G$ is trivial, is that correct?